# Bootstrap Friendly Jquery (Full-Width) Captions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hope someone can point me in the right direction and apologises if this is the wrong place to post, but thought i would shoot over a question.

I thought i would try and implement full width captions, 3 captions across 1 row, with a hover effect.

Example:
http://expressivemedia.co.uk/portfolio/

Only difference between the example and what i am looking for is i would like a full opacity cover on the hover, rather than pulling from the bottom.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to where i could perhaps see some sample code to have a play with?

Comment: Right Click => inspect element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a wrapper div, in which contains two absolutely positioned elements. You then could animate them on the hover:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wrap {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0;
}
.wrap img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.wrap .desc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  background: tomato;
}
.wrap:hover img {
  top: -100%;
}
.wrap:hover .desc {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <div class="desc">This is a nice description</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <div class="desc">This is a nice description</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <div class="desc">This is a nice description</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  <div class="desc">This is a nice description</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/dj0cq0dp/)

Answer (score 0):

For what you're looking to do, I would just use Google developer tools and just modify the CSS for your example page. This way you can play around with the settings while getting a feel for the code. What you're looking to do can be done just with CSS. The only time it is tricky is if inline styles are being added with JS.